# How do we know which term to attach a phase factor to in a state equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-states

I need to find the state of a particle in a one-dimesional harmonic oscillator where a measurement of the energy yields the values $\hbar\omega\over 2$ or $3\omega\hbar\over 2$, each with a probability of one-half at time t. I would have thought that the state would be $\big|\psi(0)\big>= {1\over \sqrt2}\big|0\big>+{1\over \sqrt2}\big|1\big>$. However the right equation is $\big|\psi(0)\big>= {1\over \sqrt2}\big|0\big>+{1\over \sqrt2}e^{-i\phi}\big|1\big>$. I know that the $e^{-i\phi}$ is a relative phase factor, but I can't figure out where it came from.

Where did the phase factor come from and when do phase factors need to be applied to the terms in state equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but there are other states that would give probability 50% and 50% if you add a phase shift to any of the states. However, any phase shift could be rewritten by a relative phase shift factor, as in the last expression in your question.